# Sonata Admin/User: "Class does not exist" (ReflectionException)

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, fosuserbundle, symfony-sonata, sonata-admin

I am currently trying to set up the SonataAdminBundle along with my custom User Bundle. My User Bundle heritates from the Sonata User Bundle using the getParent method, and SonataUserBundle heritates from FOSUserBundle using the AppKernel registration.

Everything works fine. The only problem I get is when I try to access the "add new" user from the admin dashboard, I get a "Class does not exist" error. Somehow, somewhere, symfony loses track of the class it's handling.

What frustrates me is that aside from that, everything works fine. I can view the list of users (though sometimes it displays the error "Item 'username' for '' does not exist"... most of the times in fact), groups, add groups, and all my users can log in, log off and do their deeds correctly.

My guess is that it's a bug. What's your say?

I am now using Symfony 2.1.0... Nothing changed so far.

Answer (score 0):

To me this error happend when I removed the Group Entity configuration from the Config, but then still referenced it in the Admin class... maybe it's something like that?

Answer (score 0):

For me, my EntityAdmin.php file did not have the correct permissions and sonata admin could not read it.

Make sure it's readable.